# Movie involving some kind of sentient blue being

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv

I caught a glimpse of a movie scene playing. In it, there was some kind of blue-colored being talking in a somewhat mechanical voice. It seemed to be having trouble speaking...perhaps due to being in pain. One of the lines it said was "So...many...ideas". There is another character that is turned around and looking at this blue being talking. Any ideas as to what the movie is?

Comment: You may have been watching one of several documentaries about Eiffel65’s making of their hit song, “I’m Blue.” Your figure was blue but wasn’t literally the color blue as blue-skinned. Often the song’s creators describe how full of ideas they were at the time the song was created.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Maybe a montage of clips from *Doctor Who* perhaps?

1. A clip  from the episode *[Dalek](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalek_(Doctor_Who_episode))*
   The Daleks are mutated blobs of life, in a mechanical shell. They speak in mechanical voices. In this clip, a Dalek says the exact phrase  "So... many ... ideas"  with pauses between words, and sounding in pain.

https://getyarn.io/yarn-clip/24331e4f-d922-47b1-be88-79888f3601c6

2. A character called Dorium Maldovar who is a blue man.   He  appeared in several episodes.   Here's  a picture:

[image]

And a clip on youtube.

These two  come from different episodes.  So it might have been a montage of clips, one immediately following the other

Comment: The Dalek of _Dalek_ who says “So… many… ideas…” has a blue-colored optical sensor, too.

Comment: @Silly_but_True, that's a good point.   We see the Dalek's POV several times during the episode, and people appear blue when seen through its eyestalk.  And the case opens to show the Dalek creature, which is illuminated in a blue light.    Yeah probaly that, and not Dorium.

Comment: It turned out to be the first scene you've proposed.

Answer (score 5):

You could have been watching the 24th episode of Star Trek: Deep Space Nine season 2, Episode 4, “Invasive Procedures.”

https://www.tor.com/2013/07/19/star-trek-deep-space-nine-rewatch-invasive-procedures/comment-page-2/

Posing as a cargo transport in distress, an unjoined Trill, a pair of hired Klingon mercenaries, and a former prostitute named Mareel board the station and overpower the crew.

Mareel is typically in blue with indigo accoutrements, and is in pain.

Additionally, may other people, primarily in medbay setting, are clothed or partially clothed in blue.

“So many ideas,” is stated as part of the discussion when Jadzia’s Trill is bonded:

> Curzon, Tobin, Jadzia...
> All the others. They're all a part of you now.
> **So many ideas.** So many memories.
> Eight lifetimes of memories. lt must be incredible.
> lt's better than l ever imagined. - The station must look different now.